# Flyway not finding my migrations file in sbt

Tags: scala, slick, flyway

I'm trying to apply the migrations to stand up an H2 database in test, my folder structure is:

```
src
- test
-- resources
--- db
---- migration
----- V1_0__init_tables.sql
```

I have my configuration set up to point at `classpath:db/migration` via

```
        Flyway
          .configure()
          .locations(migrateLocations)
          .dataSource(url, user, password)
          .load()
          .migrate()
```

When I run my tests I get the following output

```
2018-11-29 16:14:14,351 DEBUG [ScalaTest-run] slf4j.Slf4jLog (Slf4jLog.java:45) - Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/migration' ...
2018-11-29 16:14:14,351 DEBUG [ScalaTest-run] slf4j.Slf4jLog (Slf4jLog.java:45) - Determining location urls for classpath:db/migration using ClassLoader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2 ...
2018-11-29 16:14:14,420 WARN  [ScalaTest-run] slf4j.Slf4jLog (Slf4jLog.java:53) - Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration
2018-11-29 16:14:14,421 DEBUG [ScalaTest-run] slf4j.Slf4jLog (Slf4jLog.java:45) - Scanning for classes at classpath:db/migration
```

which leaves me confused as to why `Flyway` isn't able to find my file.  As far as I can tell I've done everything according to what the docs recommend.  My test eventually fails because my table was never migrated and thus can't be found by `Slick`.

It's possible there is an error in my migration file, but I would assume `Flyway` would have some sort of logging for this?  I don't see anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you place your migration files intentionally under `src/test/resources`? Anyway, I don't think Flyway will find them there, as your `classpath:db/migration` will most likely refer to `src/main/resources`, and not to test resources.
Just try and place your migration files under main resources.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 2 sets `spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration` as default and point to `src/main/resources/db/migration` folder regardless of you run unit testing. You can put your SQL files directory to filesystem then set `spring.flyway.locations=filesystem:path/to/yourdir`.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add sql migration scripts anywhere inside the project folder, for example in `prj_root/resources/migrations` (where `resources` is a sibling to the `src` folder).
To have it embedded as resource it needs this in `build.sbt`:

`unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "resources"`

And then to specify this location in migration code:
`Flyway.configure().locations("/migrations")...`

It also makes sense to mark this new resources directory as `Resources Root` in idea, but it's not essential, just a beautification.